# Why do I need holomorphically immersed submanifold $M\to P^m(C)$ instead of embedding to use notion of hyperplane section bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

"Moreover, a holomorphically immersed submanifold $f:M\to P^m(C)$(i.e. $m$ dimensional projective space over $C$) has an induced bundle $f^\star(H)$($H$ is hyperplane section bundle over $P^m$ or dual of universal line bundle of $P^m$) called the hyperplane section bundle of $M$."

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why do I want immersed submanifold here? Shouldn't I want embedding? In other words, I want projectively embedding of varieties? I could not see a good reason that "immersed" is a good notion to study algebraic objects. In particular, this section also involves showing all $H^{1,1}$((1,1) component of Hodge decomposition of $H^2(M)$) comes from holomorphic line bundles. This is basically showing for $M$ algebraic, all degree 2's (1,1) components are all alegbraic cycles. What is the purpose of demanding immersed here? The book did not assume $M$ compact or projective.

Ref. Chern, Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory section 6, pg 55 right before section 7.

Comment: This is not an "instead of" situation. Embeddings are immersions, so either works. The point is just that you can still reasonably pull back the line bundle and its sections (think about the inverse images of hyperplanes as opposed to just hyperplane sections).

Comment: @TabesBridges I thought embedding is much stricter notion than immersions as it demands homeo as subspace topology. Immersion cannot guarantee topological level identification. I agree embeddings are immersions but not reversed. If you consider $(-1,1)\to M$ where $M$ is figure 8 in $R^2$, this is not homeomorphism.

Comment: That's all correct. What I'm saying is that when you ask "what is the purpose of demanding immersed," you should be asking "why are we able to relax the hypothesis to immersed" since it is a weaker condition than the one you expected. And the answer is that it still makes perfectly good sense to pull back a line bundle via an immersion.